# connecting my html to mysql online using php

Tags: php, mysql, html

Below is my html code...

```
    <form action="http://mycloud.zymichost.com/registerPHP.php" method="post" id="register" data-ajax="false">
    <label>Name: <br></label>
    <input name="name" type="text" maxlength="50" ><br>
    <label>Email: <br></label>
    <input name="email" type="text" maxlength="50" ><br>
    <label>Password: <br></label>
    <input name="password" type="password" maxlength="50" ><br>
    <input name="fsubmit" type="button" value="Submit"><br>
    </form>
```

Below is my php code...

```
 <title>registerPHP</title>
 <?php

$name = $_POST ['name'];
$mail = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST ['pass'];


//$un = 'abc';
//$pw = 'abc';

$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_database = "mycloud_zymichost_register";
$mysql_user = "lorem-ipsum";
$mysql_password = "********";

    $conn = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);

    mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $conn );

    //$query = "SELECT * FROM Login WHERE username = '$un' AND password = '$pw'";
    $query = "INSERT INTO Register (name,email,pass) VALUES ('$name','$email','$pass')";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to insert user data because : " . mysql_error());  

if ($result = mysql_query($query))
    echo "Data is inserted";




    ?>
```

i cnt send the input data to my database which is mysql online.. may i know why? the sometimes null value is send to the database.. i tried input from my php.. it can.. bt using the post method in html to call the php file to insert.. the value is nt go in.. and everytime i refresh the php page.. null value will be inserted into my db...

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: I would delete the password !

Comment: Why dont you tell me your host aswell? :P

Comment: the host is mycloud.zymichost.com

Answer (score 0):

Looks like (from a guess) that you're trying to submit the form data to loginPHP but the PHP that saves the data is registerPHP?!

Comment: yeah, i hav change it to registerPHP.php.. bt it still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your formaction has loginphp.php.

Are you sure the php code you posted has the name loginphp.php?